# Как запустить таймер после того как выскочил MessageBox

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, таймер, messagebox

Всем привет! Возникла такая проблема:

Нужно зафиксировать момент появления `MessageBox` и с этого момента запустить таймер на 60 000 миллисекунд(1 минуту). Как только это время истекакает и пользователь не нажал кнопку `OK` или на крестик то закрыть форму и завершить программу. Если же пользователь нажал на кнопку `OK` или на крестик то сбросить таймер формы. Если же после того как пользователь нажал на кнопку `ОК` или на крестик но все еще не нажимает кнопки на форме то снова вывести `MessageBox` и снова запустить таймер до того момента пока не будет нажата кнопка `OK` или же крестик.
С тем как контролировать таймер во время запущенной формы и без активности пользователя я разобрался но то как запустить таймер после того как выскочил `MessageBox` и как контролировать нажата ли какая либо кнопка на этом `MessageBox` я совсем не могу придумать :( Код пробовал писать но все мои попытки не принесли успеха. Поэтому не вижу смысла здесь печатать этот код.

Буду признателен если кто-то поможет решить эту проблему :) Спасибо

Comment: MessageBox это диалог операционной системы, а не вашего приложения и без достаточно сложных штук закрыть его может только пользователь. Сделайте форму, которая будет выглядеть как он и открывайте через ShowDialog, а внутри запускайте сколько угодно таймеров.

Answer (score 0):

На примере проверки принадлежности текущего ПК к домену:

```
# Проверка принадлежит ли текущий компьютер домену. Если да - сценарий завершается с уведомлением пользователя.
if ((gwmi win32_computersystem).partofdomain -eq $true) {
$Wshell = New-Object -ComObject "Wscript.Shell"
# Вывод сообщения: текст, таймаут ожидания реакции до автовыбора, заголовок окна, тип кнопок + тип иконки
$Message = $Wshell.Popup("This PC is already in Domain",5,"Nothing is required",0+16)
Exit
}
```